# Boton dropdown no funciona

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sigo trabajando con  Boostraap,html,css,js y ahora el dropdown donde dice "team" la idea es que te mande a una seccion pero no me esta funcionando y asi lo tengo estructurado.... alguien sabe poorque?

```
<li class="dropdown" data-animation="fadeIn">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="contact.html"
data-title="Home"> TEAM </a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu no-border-radius">
<li><a href="team.html"> # </a></li>
<li><a href="team.html"> # </a></li>
<li><a href="team.html"> # </a></li>
<li><a href="team.html"> # </a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
```

Comment: No se entiende el problema

Answer (score 0):

Lo más probable es que no añadiste todas las librerías de JavaScript que brindan la funcionalidad a ciertos componentes de Bootstrap. Puedes consultar su implementación en la [introducción a Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/) y algunos ejemplos y requerimientos del [dropdown](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/).

**CSS** (en el `<head></head>`)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

**JS** (antes del `</body>`)

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Por ende, así debería lucir tu código para que funcione:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Ejemplo de Dropdown Bootstrap -->
    <div class="dropdown show">
      <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown link
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Tu código en funcionamiento -->
    <li class="dropdown" data-animation="fadeIn">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="contact.html"
        data-title="Home"> TEAM </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu no-border-radius">
            <li><a href="team.html"> Elemento 1 </a></li>
            <li><a href="team.html"> Elemento 2 </a></li>
            <li><a href="team.html"> Elemento 3 </a></li>
            <li><a href="team.html"> Elemento 4 </a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```